# Identify the smallest value from multiplied values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

[image]

In **Column A** you can find different products. In **Column B** the `number of orders` of each product and in **Column C** the `profit per product`. 
In **Column D** the `total profit` for each product is calculated by multiply the values in **Column B** with the values in **Column C**.

In **Column E** the product with the **lowest** `total profit` is displayed by using the following formula:

```
=IF(D2=SMALL($D$2:$D$7,1),"Lowest","")
```

All this works fine so far.

Now I want to get rid of **Column D** because it only serves as a `helper column` in order to identify the product with the **lowest** `total profit`.

How do I have to modify my formula in **Column E** to show the **lowest** `total profit` without the **helper Column D**.

I was thinking about something like this: 
 `=IF(B2 x C2 =SMALL($B$2:$B$7 x $C$2:$C$7,1),"Lowest","")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That formula works as an array - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the formula bar

`=IF(B2*C2 =SMALL($B$2:$B$7*$C$2:$C$7,1),"Lowest","")` if you done it right it will wrap it in `{ }`